# How to force user to use an application at start of Windows

Tags: windows

We have an application that checks if the user's password is expired, and in that case, the user is asked to change its password.

We would like to force to user to change the password before using Windows 7.

The problem is that the user can close the window, kill the process, or simply move the change pwd window on the side, ignore it and continue to work on Windows.

What solution do you recommend to achieve this goal?

We thought of locking Windows while running the change pwd app exclusively, but we don't see how to do this.
Using policies to force running only this application just after Windows login? But where is the expiration check done and how the policies can be set?

Thanks for you advices.

Comment: Why do you need an application at all? Windows will prompt you to change your password anyway when it expires.

Comment: If the password is expired, the user shouldn't be able to log in before he/she changes it. What do you need an application for?

Comment: You're right. Our application allows to change a single password on both Windows and IBM AS400 for customers who work with both systems.

Comment: You could change the Shell setting in the Winlogon registry key to point to your application.  (Your application will have to launch Explorer once it is done.)